# React-ga not returning correct active page in Google Analytics Dashboard

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-slick, react-ga

**Context:** In the app, I am using react-slick to allows users to navigate through components like a carousel. (NOTE: as users navigate through the carousel, the URL for the application does not change/update; always *https: //myApplicationURL.com*)

**What I am attempting to accomplish:** Each component within the carousel uses react-ga to initialize and track pageview analytics on a component level.

**What I expect:** Google Analytics dashboard will return the correct component name a user is currently viewing.

**What is actually happening:** Google Analytics dashboard displays an incorrect component name. (Ex: application is on contact component - should display '/contact' but GA dashboard displays another component name)

---

```
**CAROUSEL COMPONENT**
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import About from '../../components/about';
import {default as Project1} from '../../components/projectTemplate';
import {default as Project2} from '../../components/projectTemplate';
import {default as Project3} from '../../components/projectTemplate';
import {default as Project4} from '../../components/projectTemplate';
import Contact from '../../components/contact';

export default class Carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nav1: null,
      nav2: null,
      pageNumber: 0
    };
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      nav1: this.slider1,
      nav2: this.slider2
    });
  }

  afterChangeHandler = currentSlide => {
    this.setState({
      pageNumber: currentSlide++
    })
  };

  render() {
    const carousel1 = {
      asNavFor: this.state.nav2,
      ref: slider => (this.slider1 = slider),
      afterChange: this.afterChangeHandler
    }

    const carousel2 = {
      asNavFor: this.state.nav1,
      ref: slider => (this.slider2 = slider),
    } 

    return (
      <div id="carousel-container">
          <Slider {...carousel1}>
            <div>
              <About props={this.props.props} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Project1 project={this.props.props.project[0]} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Project2 project={this.props.props.project[1]} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Project3 project={this.props.props.project[2]} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Project4 project={this.props.props.project[3]} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <Contact {/*props*/} />
            </div>
          </Slider>
          <Slider {...carousel2}>
            {/*slider2 content*/}
          </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


**ABOUT COMPONENT**
import React from 'react';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

const About = props => {
    //Google Analytics
    ReactGA.initialize('[User ID removed]');
    ReactGA.ga('set', 'page', '/about');
    ReactGA.ga('send', 'pageview');

  return(
    <div id="aboutContainer">
        {/*Component Content*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;


**PROJECT COMPONENT**
import React from 'react';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

const ProjectTemp = props => {
  const name = props.project.name

  // Google Analytics
  ReactGA.initialize('[User ID removed]');
  ReactGA.ga('set', 'page', `/project/${name}`);
  ReactGA.ga('send', 'pageview');

  return(
    <div id="projectTempContainer">
      {/*Project Content*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectTemp;


**CONTACT COMPONENT**
import React from 'react';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

const Contact = props => {
  //Google Analytics
    ReactGA.initialize('[User ID removed]');
    ReactGA.ga('set', 'page', '/contact');
    ReactGA.ga('send', 'pageview');

  return(
    <div id="contactContainer">
      {/*Contact Content*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Segment analytics library and following our [React quickstart guide](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react) to track page calls. If you are rendering individual components inside the carousel, you can use `componentDidMount` to invoke `page` calls. You’ll be able to manually set the page name via the parameter, which will help you avoid the issue you’re having with `/contact`. The example below shows one way you could do this:

```
export default class CarouselContact extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.analytics.page('Contact');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        Contact page.
      </h1>
    );
  }
}
```

I’m the maintainer of https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react. With Segment, you’ll be able to switch different destinations on-and-off by the flip of a switch if you are interested in trying multiple analytics tools (we support over 250+ destinations) without having to write any additional code.